# Is it possible to map a choice field selection to a foreign key in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

## models.py

```
class Testimonials(models.Model):
client = 'client'
employee = 'employee'
general = 'general'
Testimonial_Choices = (
    ('client', 'client'),
    ('employee', 'employee'),
    ('general', 'general'),
)
testimonial_type=models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=Testimonial_Choices, default=client)
if testimonial_type=='client':
    client_name= models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
content= models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False)
posted_date= models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.client_name
```

## admin.py

```
class TestimonialAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('testimonial_type', 'posted_date')
list_filter = ('testimonial_type', 'posted_date')
search_fields = ['testimonial_type', 'posted_date']
empty_value_display = '-- NA --'
list_per_page = 10
```

```
admin.site.register(Testimonials, TestimonialAdmin)
```

I am trying to add a choice field first and if the choice type is client i want to fetch the client name and image

## error

```
AttributeError: 'Testimonials' object has no attribute 'client_name'
```

Comment: you cannot dynamically add columns in database.

Comment: @SadanA.Oh Ok.. Thanks for that.. Is it possible to hide/show the next option otherwise?